# "Making Do" or "Make Do"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage

Consider the following sentence

> At present, I'm making do with what I have

Though it tells you what I'm trying to convey, something feels funny about the phrase "making do". Is it grammatically wrong? Will I have to rephrase the sentence to read as

> At present, I've to make do with what I have

PS: Googling "making do" isn't helping either as the results that are showing up are related to "make do"

Comment: Why should only one of them be correct or better by itself?

Comment: Well, this wasn't really about which one is better. It actually is about if the first version is grammatically correct or not

Comment: "Why should only one of them be correct?"

Comment: You could ask that to someone who already knew that both are correct. I didn't and hence I posed a query.....

Comment: I can see that the OP is a recent entrant to ELU. The asker is not expected to *know*, but is expected to *make an effort* to find out and show it. Also, please read the FAQs.

Comment: I understand that. And I did make an effort before posting here. It's just that the Google results weren't conclusive.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is fine. It is *not* grammatically wrong. And the "make do" idiom still works when changed to "making do."

The second version is problematic. You need to add the word "what", like so:

> At present, I have to make do with *what* I have.

However, the duplication of "have" makes this version weaker. Stick with your first version.

Comment: That constitutes proof-reading/ writing advice. Please avoid.

Comment: My bad. That was a typo. I missed the "what" in the sentence. So in essence, both the versions are correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

The second is much natural as

***Lately/Recently***, I'**ve had** to make do with what I have.

Now, you have a complete present perfect version of the verb in place, as well as an adverbial that better fits it.